# Filter date in datetime objects by month

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I have a dictionary where the keys are datetime.datetime & the values are lists of tweets.  So it looks like this:

```
{datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 30, 19, 55, 20) : ['this is some tweet text'],
 datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 30, 19, 55, 20) : ['this is another tweet']...
```

I'm trying to get the number of tweets sent out each month of the year.  So far I have...

```
startDate = 10
endDate= 11
start = True
while start:

    for k,v in tweetDict.items():
        endDate-=1
        startDate-=1

        datetimeStart = datetime(2017, startDate, 1)
        datetimeEnd = datetime(2017,endDate, 1)

        print(datetimeStart, datetimeEnd)

        if datetimeStart < k < datetimeEnd:
            print(v)
        if endDate == 2:
            start = False
            break
```

which only prints (I'm aware of the print statement)...

```
2017-08-01 00:00:00 2017-09-01 00:00:00
2017-07-01 00:00:00 2017-08-01 00:00:00
2017-06-01 00:00:00 2017-07-01 00:00:00
2017-05-01 00:00:00 2017-06-01 00:00:00
2017-04-01 00:00:00 2017-05-01 00:00:00
2017-03-01 00:00:00 2017-04-01 00:00:00
2017-02-01 00:00:00 2017-03-01 00:00:00
2017-01-01 00:00:00 2017-02-01 00:00:00
```

and not the actual tweets themselves.  I was expecting something like ...

```
2017-08-01 00:00:00 2017-09-01 00:00:00
['heres a tweet']
['theres a tweet']
2017-07-01 00:00:00 2017-08-01 00:00:00
['there only 1 tweet for this month']....
```

I'm kinda stuck, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can just [group by](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) the month instead of trying to subtract/compare different months:

```
>>> d = {datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 30, 19, 55, 20): ['this is some tweet text'],
         datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 30, 20, 55, 20): ['this is another tweet'],
         datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 30, 19, 55, 20): ['this is an october tweet'],}
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> for month, group in groupby(d.items(), lambda (k, v): k.month):
...     print(month)
...     for dt, tweet in group:
...         print(dt, tweet)
...         
10
2017-10-30 19:55:20 ['this is an october tweet']
9
2017-09-30 19:55:20 ['this is some tweet text']
2017-09-30 20:55:20 ['this is another tweet']
>>>
```

And of course, you can print it in a nicer format and so on (inner join is needed because each key seems to be a list):

```
>>> for month, group in groupby(d.items(), lambda (k, v): k.month):
...     tweets = list(group)
...     print("%d tweet(s) in month %d" % (len(tweets), month))
...     print('\n'.join(','.join(tweet) for (dt, tweet) in tweets))
...     
1 tweet(s) in month 10
this is an october tweet
2 tweet(s) in month 9
this is some tweet text
this is another tweet
>>>
```

Comment: I see how groupby would be easier in this instance but I keep getting an`SyntaxError`  in the first line of the for loop, right under the `(k,v)`.  I'm using python 3.  Would that make a difference since your code looks like python 2?

Comment: Ah yes, apologies, @e1v1s change all `print x` to `print(x)` (I don't have python 3 installed on this machine).

Comment: Yes, I already added the parenthesis around the print statements.  the `Syntax Error` is mentioned in the above comment :)

Comment: @e1v1s could you post the full stacktrace and/or screenshot? Maybe the spacing or formatting is off? I'll take another look when I get my hands on a machine with Python 3 (most likely when I get home)

Answer (score 0):

First thing: you're putting two items in your dict with the exact same key. The second one will overwrite the first. For the rest of this, I'm going to assume that the second item in your example is slightly different (`seconds=21`).

The reason your code isn't working as you expect is because you're decrementing `endDate` and `startDate` inside your `for` loop. As a result, you're only checking each date against a single item in the dict; if that item happens to land in that month, it gets printed. If not, it doesn't. To illustrate, here's what you get if you change your `print` to `print(datetimeStart, datetimeEnd, k, v)`:

```
2017-09-01 00:00:00 2017-10-01 00:00:00 2017-09-30 19:55:20 ['this is some tweet text']
['this is some tweet text']
2017-08-01 00:00:00 2017-09-01 00:00:00 2017-09-30 19:55:21 ['this is another tweet']
2017-07-01 00:00:00 2017-08-01 00:00:00 2017-09-30 19:55:20 ['this is some tweet text']
2017-06-01 00:00:00 2017-07-01 00:00:00 2017-09-30 19:55:21 ['this is another tweet']
2017-05-01 00:00:00 2017-06-01 00:00:00 2017-09-30 19:55:20 ['this is some tweet text']
2017-04-01 00:00:00 2017-05-01 00:00:00 2017-09-30 19:55:21 ['this is another tweet']
2017-03-01 00:00:00 2017-04-01 00:00:00 2017-09-30 19:55:20 ['this is some tweet text']
2017-02-01 00:00:00 2017-03-01 00:00:00 2017-09-30 19:55:21 ['this is another tweet']
2017-01-01 00:00:00 2017-02-01 00:00:00 2017-09-30 19:55:20 ['this is some tweet text']
```

The fix with the least change to your existing code would be to simply move the decrements in front of the `for` loop and dedent the `if endDate...` block to the level of the `while` loop:

```
while start:
    endDate-=1
    startDate-=1
    for k,v in tweetDict.items():
        datetimeStart = datetime(2017, startDate, 1)
        datetimeEnd = datetime(2017,endDate, 1)
        print(datetimeStart, datetimeEnd, k, v)
        if datetimeStart < k < datetimeEnd:
            print(v)
    if endDate == 2:
        start = False
        break
```

Of course, at that point you might as well just get rid of the `if endDate...` block and do `while endDate > 2:`.